# Angular6: RxJS switchMap operator is not working as expected

Tags: angular, rxjs6

In my angular 6 application, I want to filter before it `switchMap` to inner Observable as below:

Basically, What I want to do is if the store selector gives me pertaining data for a given string I will use the response in `switchMap` to fire the inner observable and will do a subscription.

The idea here is that if filtration succeeds do find and data for the filters response using `switchMap`

```
 this._store.pipe(select(getDetails)).pipe(map((details: detail[]) => {
    return of(details.filter(({ tagName }) => tagName ===this.videoTagName))})
   switchMap((data:detail)=>this._store.pipe(select(getVideosByID(data.contentIds[0]))))).subscribe(data=>{
      console.log("Data",data)
   })
```

The above code gives the error below:

```
Type 'detail' is missing the following properties from type 'Observable<detail[]>': _isScalar, source, operator, lift, and 10 more.ts(2345)
```

will `combineLatest` help here? or something I need to do with `switchMap` only.. ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things:

1. You should probably define types or classes/interfaces in a way that they won't conflict with variables. Usually people will capitalize types, for instance you'd have `type Detail = ...` so that you can then define `const detail: Detail = ...`.
2. Assuming that a detail is not an Observable, you should not use `of` in the "project" argument of RxJs's `map`. The "project" argument of `map` is a function that takes as its argument the value emitted by an observable, and returns a new value that will be emitted instead. Here if you return `of`, your Observable will emit an Observable (which is *usually* not what you want). This is why you get your error: `switchMap` right below expects to be piped to an Observable that emits a `detail`, but instead it gets an `Observable<detail[]>`. If you fix that, you'll emit `details` instead of `detail`, which isn't perfect yet but we're getting closer.
3. If you want to filter a unique detail (and not a list of details), you should use `.find()` instead of `.filter()`. Filtering returns an array of all elements that match the predicate (maybe it's an array of 1 element only, but it's still an array). Find returns the first element that matches. Now we're emitting a `detail`, so the typing inside switchMap will be ok and the error will go away.
4. You don't need to chain `.pipe()` calls, you can just chain the arguments inside of a single pipe. This applies to the first two pipes, but obviously not to the one inside the switchMap, since if you move it inside of the "main" pipe, `detail` won't be in the scope anymore.

With all of this, you get the following code, which should work:

```js
this._store.pipe(
  select(getDetails),
  map((details: Detail[]) => details.find(
    ({ tagName }) => tagName === this.videoTagName
  )),
  switchMap((detail: Detail) => this._store.pipe(
    select(getVideosByID(detail.contentIds[0])),
  )),
).subscribe(data => console.log("Data", data));
```

Comment: Ok!! let me give a try

Comment: This was it, excellent answer, I messed up in my naming convention.